# How to input data to DB using ORM with relationed tables

Tags: node.js, typeorm

hi guys i have 3 tables
Order
Patient
Sample
Relations: Order-samples 1-many, patient-samples 1-many

when creating an order post request  i receive 2 fields date and array of objects samples with field patientId and sample name.

How is it possible to insert data to database securelly using typeorm? i would like to roll back if sth happen at any stage of adding the data to DB . Shall i use transaction from type orm for doing it? if so i am not pretty sure how to do it.
any examples of code please .

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like [this section](https://typeorm.io/transactions#using-queryrunner-to-create-and-control-state-of-single-database-connection) of the TypeORM docs that explains fine-grained control of a transaction, particularly the section using `rollbackTransaction()`.